# Redirect to URL based on form input

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have a user input a number and be redirected based on where in a range that number falls. It works if use text inputs and assign each input to the corresponding URL but doesn't work when I use a number input.

My code right now is

```
<html>
<div align=center>
  <br>
<form method="post" id="TEST"> 
<input type="number" id="command" tabindex="1">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="redirect me">
</form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function() {

    if ($('#command').val() >= 46) {
      window.location = "http://www.example.com/46";
    }

    else if ($('#command').val() > 46.1 && > 50) {
      window.location = "http://www.example.com/49";

    }

    else if ($('#command').val() === 50) {
      window.location = "http://www.example.com/50";
    }

    else if ($('#command').val() >= 50.1 && <= 52) {
      window.location = "http://www.example.com/52";
    }

    else if ($('#command').val() >= 52.1 && <= 53) {
      window.location = "http://www.example.com/53";
    }

    else if ($('#command').val() >= 53.1 && <= 54) {
      window.location = "http://www.example.com/54"
    }

    else if ($('#command').val() >= 54.1 && <= 56 {
      window.location = "http://www.example.com/56"
    }

    else return false;
  });

  });
});
</script>

</html>
```

I'm sure it's something obvious but I can't work it out. Any solutions appreciated!

Comment: You need to use command again after the `&&` so `... && $('#command').val() >= 46` I would save the value of `$('#command').val()` to a variable for readability.

Comment: Marco, if you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as accepted on the left side from answer. In other case please write a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare `$('#command').val()` on both sides of the `&&`. You need to think of each grouping as its own brand new comparison. Here are the first two if statements:

```
let command = $('#command').val()
if (command >= 46) {
  window.location = "http://www.example.com/46";
}

else if (command > 46.1 && command > 50) {
  window.location = "http://www.example.com/49";

}
```

You are missing a `)` in the last `else if`. also instead of returning `false`, we can just call `e.preventDefault()` which will prevent the default behavior of the element, in this case a form submit.

Another thing we will want to do is reverse the order of the if/else statements, because once you use a number larger than or equal to `46` that first statement will run, and since all other test numbers are larger than `46`, it will never get to them since the first statement already executed as `true`.

Your html input field is set as a number, but your javascript allows for floats, we cannot enter a float into a number field without a step attribute, so I added `step="0.01"` to the input field.

In the example below, I replaced `window.location` with `console.log` for stack overflow purposes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    // Stop the form from submiting
    e.preventDefault()
    // Save a reference to the value
    let command = parseFloat($('#command').val())
    // Test the values from highest to lowest
    if (command >= 54.1 && command <= 56) {
      console.log("http://www.example.com/56");
    } else if (command >= 53.1 && command <= 54) {
      console.log("http://www.example.com/54");
    } else if (command >= 52.1 && command <= 53) {
      console.log("http://www.example.com/53");
    } else if (command >= 50.1 && command <= 52) {
      console.log("http://www.example.com/52");
    } else if (command === 50) {
      console.log("http://www.example.com/50");
    } else if (command > 46.1 && command > 50) {
      console.log("http://www.example.com/49");
    } else if (command >= 46) {
      console.log("http://www.example.com/46");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="TEST">
  <input type="number" id="command" tabindex="1" step="0.01">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="redirect me">
</form>
```

Comment: Ah that makes complete sense! I can see why it should technically work now but I changed the code to reflect that and inputting any number still simply results in a false return (I think - the browser essentially doesn't react to the from submission). Anything else that looks wrong there? (I appreciate your help. Still learning and overly ambitious it seems).

Comment: Thank you so much. All of this was massively educational. The order of the else if statements especially. Will go learn more about floats now as well. Really appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code syntax is completly wrong. I corrected it. See my comments below in the code.

But the biggest mistake in your code – you write

```
if ($('#command').val() >= 50.1 && <= 52)
```

instead of:

```
if ($('#command').val() >= 50.1 && $('#command').val() <= 52)
```

and so on...

**Corrected code:**

```
$("form").submit(function()
{
    var val = $('#command').val(); //Suggestion: please use $('#command').val() only one time

    if(val <= 46) // >= was wrong
    {
        window.location = "http://www.example.com/46";
    }

    else if(val > 46.1 && val < 50) // > 50 was wrong
    {
        window.location = "http://www.example.com/49";
    }

    else if(val == 50) //do not use "===" because your value is a string! Or convert it to number
    {
        window.location = "http://www.example.com/50";
    }

    else if(val >= 50.1 && val <= 52)
    {
        window.location = "http://www.example.com/52";
    }

    else if (val >= 52.1 && val <= 53)
    {
        window.location = "http://www.example.com/53";
    }

    else if(val >= 53.1 && val <= 54)
    {
        window.location = "http://www.example.com/54"
    }

    else if(val >= 54.1 && val <= 56) // one ) symbol was missed
    {
        window.location = "http://www.example.com/56"
    }

    else return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is identity-comparing strings to floats, and your second comparisons are missing the value to compare against.

Convert the values to float first, specify which value with for your second compare in your else-ifs and it will do as you intend:

```
var value = parseFloat($('#command').val());
if (value >= 46) {
    window.location = "http://www.example.com/46";
} 
else if (value > 46.1 && value > 50) {
    window.location = "http://www.example.com/49";
}
[ ... ]
```

Comment: `"1" < 10 == true` and `"1" > 10 == false`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn He has `$('#command').val() === 50`, which will evaluate to `false` even if the input is `50`.

Comment: I didn't see that one.